# AC circuit to act as a relay for another DC circuit

Tags: ac, dc, zener, thyristor, voltmeter

[image]

In this circuit, I have caused an AC current to power the gate pin of the Thyristor, which in turn should allow the 10v DC current to pass even after the AC current inverses - it is not a Transistor. However, when I check to see the voltage after the Thyristor (at the Voltmeter), the value is always fluctuating from positive to negative - as you can see, the Anode pin of the Thyristor is receiving the full 10v, so why is the voltage fluctuating so much after the Cathode pin?

Comment: Try adding a load resistor and pointing out where 0V is.

Comment: It is unclear what the purpose of this circuit is. What are you trying to achieve ? Where is the ground ? 10 V, is that a voltage source ? I suggest you study and try to understand other Thyristor based circuits, learn how to use a thyristor.

Comment: You have no GND connection for your 10 V supply so there is no return path.

Comment: Does the AC signal need to be as low as 1Hz!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only works with high frequency AC input.

[image: circuit]

Is this what you mean?

If you want to allow lower frequencies, you would need a LC or an RC filter, where they have to be pretty large values.